# LINQ to Entity Framwework Multiple Joins with Multiple Dynamic Search Criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

The gist of the problem is that we have an alumni table (one record per person) and also a couple of other tables (one to many) that have degree info and interest info.  In a search screen in our app you can search for criteria that spans all three tables (there are actually more fields and tables than shown in the example below but I am trying to keep it simple).

The code below works (properly returns people without degrees for example) but still feels a little clunky or over-engineered to me.  Are there easier ways to do this?  NOTE: I have been through quite a few iterations/approaches to making the correct data be returned.

```
 public IQueryable<AlumniSearchResult> FindAlumniRecords(AlumniSearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        // tables
        var alumniRecords = iuaaOlcEntities.AlumniRecords.AsQueryable();
        var degreeRecords = iuaaOlcEntities.AlumniDegrees.AsQueryable();
        var interestRecords = iuaaOlcEntities.AlumniInterests.AsQueryable();

        // typed predicates
        var alumniRecordPredicates = PredicateBuilder.True<AlumniRecord>(); // True for AND, False for OR???
        var degreePredicates = PredicateBuilder.True<AlumniDegree>();
        var interestPredicates = PredicateBuilder.True<AlumniInterest>();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.lastname))
            alumniRecordPredicates = alumniRecordPredicates.And(item => item.lastname.StartsWith(searchCriteria.lastname));
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.firstname))
            alumniRecordPredicates = alumniRecordPredicates.And(item => item.firstname.StartsWith(searchCriteria.firstname));
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.nickname))
            alumniRecordPredicates = alumniRecordPredicates.And(item => item.nickname.StartsWith(searchCriteria.nickname));
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.maiden_lastname))
            alumniRecordPredicates = alumniRecordPredicates.And(item => item.maiden_lastname.StartsWith(searchCriteria.maiden_lastname));
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.city))
            alumniRecordPredicates = alumniRecordPredicates.And(item => item.city.StartsWith(searchCriteria.city));


        // degrees
        if (searchCriteria.school_name != null)
            degreePredicates = degreePredicates.And(item => item.school_name.Contains(searchCriteria.school_name));
        if (searchCriteria.degree_name != null)
            degreePredicates = degreePredicates.And(item => item.name.Contains(searchCriteria.degree_name));
        if (searchCriteria.major != null)
            degreePredicates = degreePredicates.And(item => (item.major1_name.Contains(searchCriteria.major) || item.major2_name.Contains(searchCriteria.major) || item.major3_name.Contains(searchCriteria.major)));

        // interests
        if (searchCriteria.interests != null)
            interestRecords = interestRecords.Where(item => item.interest_desc.Contains(searchCriteria.interests));

        // the queries aren't running yet but applying the predicates outside of the join
        alumniRecords = from a in iuaaOlcEntities.AlumniRecords.Where(alumniRecordPredicates).AsExpandable()
                        select a;
        degreeRecords = from b in iuaaOlcEntities.AlumniDegrees.Where(degreePredicates).AsExpandable()
                        select b;
        interestRecords = from c in iuaaOlcEntities.AlumniInterests.Where(interestPredicates).AsExpandable()
                        select c;

        return (from a in alumniRecords
                join b in degreeRecords on a.person_id equals b.person_id into temp1
                from t1 in temp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join c in interestRecords on t1.person_id equals c.person_id into temp2
                from t2 in temp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new AlumniSearchResult
                {
                    person_id = a.person_id,
                    fullname = a.lastname + ", " + (a.firstname ?? "") + " " + (a.mid_name ?? ""),
                    emp_city = a.emp_city,
                    emp_state = a.emp_state,
                    emp_name = a.emp_name,
                    emp_title = a.emp_title
                }).Distinct();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the DynamicQuery library here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Maybe you can explain how you fill the AlumniSearchCriteria (UI -> AlumniSearchCriteria).

Comment: I have looked at that but didn't find anything easier.  May just be me being a noob at this though.  I have tried many different things but usually get errors when trying to merge examples of where clauses and joins.

The search criteria is just an object that holds the values from a simple form input.  Fill in values to search by, click Search.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var SearchData(string sc1, string sc2, string sc3, string sc4)
    {

var res = (from t1 in T1
join t2 in T2 on t1.AnyField equals t2.CorrespondentField
join t3 in T3 on t1.AnyField equals t3.CorrespondentField

where (t1.AnyField.Equals(sc1) || String.IsEmptyOrNull(sc1))
&& (t2.AnyField.Equals(sc2) || String.IsEmptyOrNull(sc2))
&& ( 
 (t3.AnyField.Equals(sc3) || String.IsEmptyOrNull(sc3)
&& 
(t3.AnyField.Equals(sc4) || String.IsEmptyOrNull(sc4)
)
);
return res.ToList();
}
```